# Getting error in while controller expression in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am getting this exception in while controller using jmeter-maven-plugin.

expression:

```
${__javaScript("${type}" != "reports" && ${counter} < 300;)}
```

Error -

```
jmeter.functions.JavaScript: Error processing Javascript: ["${type}" != "reports" && ${counter} < 100;]
 org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing ; before statement (<cmd>#1
```

Comment: can you please show us how you defined **type** and **counter** variables?

Comment: @Naveen I am extracting value for type from api response and counter is used to not go in infinite loop

Comment: As Dmitri mentioned, use Debug Sampler and View Results Tree to check what these variable contains during the run-time. because from the logs, we can clearly say that these value are not being replaced as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your While Controller expression.

Given you see `${type}` and `${counter}` in the log instead of real values the `type` and `counter` variables are not set so double check the way you're setting the variables and verify the values using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.

See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more information on JMeter tests troubleshooting.